# How prepend appropriate amount of 0's to numbers contained in image names?

Tags: shell, filenames, string

I've got a folder `/User/me/Desktop/folder/images` with files like `key 1--name.jpg`, `key 10--name1.jpg`, etc. The files are sorted incorrectly when fed to my site so I get an arrangement like `key 84--name.jpg -> key 9--name.jpg -> key 94--name.jpg` instead of `key 9--name.jpg -> key 84--name.jpg -> key 94--name.jpg` because of character precedence. So I wan to replace all the non-three-digit-length image names like `9, 12, 99` with their three-digit, 0-padded equivalents to get `009, 012, 099` so the ordering will be correct. How can this be done for folder full of files in one line in my Mac terminal.

Comment: Please see the accepted answer on [THIS POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789729/how-to-zero-pad-a-sequence-of-integers-in-bash-so-that-all-have-the-same-width). You need to do some homework, like parsing the file name and extracting the sequence number and reforming the filename but you can figure out the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Extraxt the number, something like:

```
$ echo 'key 88--name.jpg' | sed 's/key \([0-9]\+\)--.*/\1/'
88
```

Format it with printf:

```
$ printf '%04d' "88"
0088
```

reinsert that into the name:

```
$ echo 'key 88--name.jpg' | sed 's/\(key [0-9]\+--\)/key 0088--/'
key 0088--name.jpg
```

All in one script:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in 'key '*'--name.jpg'; do
    a="$( echo "$f" | sed 's/key \([0-9]\+\)--.*/\1/' )"
    b="$( printf '%04d' "$a" )"
    c="$( echo "$f" | sed 's/\(key '"$a"'--\)/key '"$b"'--/' )"
    echo \
    mv -i "$f" "$c"
done
```

Or even faster:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in 'key '*'--name.jpg'; do
    a="${f#key }"
    a="${a%--name.jpg}"
    b="$( printf 'key %04d--name.jpg' "$a" )"
    echo \
    mv -i "$f" "$b"
done
```

Both scripts will **not** change anything. They will just list what is going to be changed. If you are happy with what you see, just comment out (add a # in front of) the line `echo \`. In any case, the mv command will not overwrite any file if the file already exists (the -i option).

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance how many digits to pad to, this can be done fairly simply by combining the shell's string manipulation and arithmetic features. To pad to 3 digits, number from 1000 and strip away the leading `1`.

```
for current_name in *[0-9]*; do
  # Split the name into prefix, digits, suffix
  prefix=${current_name%%[0-9]*}; suffix=${current_name#"$prefix"}
  # Pad the digits
  digits=${suffix%%[!0-9]*}; suffix=${suffix#"$digits"}
  digits=$((digits+1000)); digits=${digits#1}
  # Rename the file
  new_name="$prefix$digits$suffix"
  if [ "$new_name" != "$current_name" ]; then
    mv -- "$current_name" "$new_name"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function computes the number of necessary digits (1 for up to 9 files, 2 for up to 99 files, a.s.o.) and renames the files with the first number in the filename padded with zeros accordingly:

```bsh
pad_numbers_with_zeros(){
  folder="$1"
  [[ -d "$folder" ]] || { echo 'need directory argument' && return; }
  extension="$2"
  [[ -z "$extension" ]] && extension=wav
  digits="$3"
  if [[ -z "$digits" ]]; then
    amount=$(ls "$folder"/*.$extension | wc -l)
    digits=$(echo "l($amount)/l(10)+1" | bc -l)
  fi
  fmt=$(printf '%%0%dd' $digits)
  for f in "$folder"/*.$extension; do
    bn=$(basename "$f")
    number=$(echo $bn | sed -re 's/^[^[:digit:]]*0*([[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*)[^[:digit:]].*/\1/')
    [[ "$bn" == "$number" ]] && continue
    pf_pat=$(echo $bn | sed -re "s/0*$number/$fmt/")
    new_path=$(printf "$folder/$pf_pat" $number)
    [[ "$f" != "$new_path" ]] &&  mv -i "$f" "$new_path"
  done
}
```

For `.jpg`-files call with a second argument `jpg`. This makes of course only sense if filenames have consecutive numbers in them. Alternatively the number of desired digits can be passed as third argument.